# Play2 java with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework

I am very new to play framework. I am trying to make a simple Java TODO application as per the https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList. The first step of was successful. Now I am trying to make mongodb as my datastore and I am unable to find any pointers on how to bootstrap my application with mongodb connections sorted out.

All I have for now is the mongodb dependency added in my `build.sbt` file as follows,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.13.0"
)
```

How do I change this sample application to use mongodb datastore? I was able to find plenty of pointers on reactivemongo etc..but I just want to use the mango java driver to start with. Any pointers or tutorials on how to go about this would be helpful.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with Mongo but definitely you have to set up coordinated to your Mongo DB via application.conf

You probably should look these line in *.conf file

```
db.default.driver=yourDriver
db.default.url=coordinates to your DB
db.default.user=...
db.default.password="...
```

this is a db connection...

```
http://ebooks24.org/9781617290909.html
```

Maybe one from those books would be helpful for you 
In play for java book i saw example with twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MongoDB Salat plugin for Play Framework 2](https://github.com/leon/play-salat).

Brief

In **project/Build.scala**  add

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "se.radley" %% "play-plugins-salat" % "1.5.0"
)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  routesImport += "se.radley.plugin.salat.Binders._",
  templatesImport += "org.bson.types.ObjectId"
)
```

In **conf/play.plugins**

`500:se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin`

In **conf/application.conf**

disable plugins

```
dbplugin = disabled
evolutionplugin = disabled
ehcacheplugin = disabled
```

set up configuration

```
mongodb.default.db = "mydb"
# Optional values
#mongodb.default.host = "127.0.0.1"
#mongodb.default.port = 27017
#mongodb.default.user = "leon"
#mongodb.default.password = "123456"
```

For more details check the given link.